# django recurrent model lookup

Tags: python, django, model, querying

I have a recurrent Category model (each category could have a parent Category), I also have Product model with ForeignKey to "core category" as below. Is there any possibility to query all Products within top level categories (not core)?

For example, my Categories Tree is:

```
---Sales (main) (parent = None)
    ---Crm (core) (parent = Sales)
    ---Marketing Automation (core) (parent = Sales)
    ---AI (parent = Sales)
       ---BOTS (core) (parent = AI)
       ---NLP (core) (parent = AI)
```

I want to query all product in "Sales" or "AI"

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    core = models.BooleanField()
    main = models.BooleanField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                               null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** I think the best equivalent for this particular situation are files in folders. Single File (Product) knows only its parent directory (core Category), but this parent directory could be a sub-folder of its parent. I want to query top level folder (Category) for all files (Products) in subdirectories.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @SachinKukreja so far I tried a loop where I checked which categories have a particular parent, and go deeper with the upper-level parent, finally store all "cores" in an array and check their Products. But I'm curious if there is a one query solution without loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get all sub-categories by using reverse foreign key lookup `category_set` on a `Category` instance.

**Solution**:

```
def recursive_sub_category(top_level_category_name, sub_core_categories=None):
    if sub_core_categories is None:
        sub_core_categories = list()

    top_level_category = Category.objects.get(name=top_level_category_name)

    _sub_core_categories = top_level_category.category_set.filter(core=True, main=False)

    if _sub_core_categories.count() > 0:
        sub_core_categories.append(*_sub_core_categories)

    sub_main_categories = top_level_category.category_set.filter(main=True, core=False)
    for category in sub_main_categories:
        _sub_core_categories = recursive_sub_category(
            category.name,
            sub_core_categories=sub_core_categories
        )
        if len(_sub_core_categories) > 0:
            sub_core_categories.append(*_sub_core_categories)

    return sub_core_categories

sub_core_categories = recursive_sub_category("Sales")
core_products_under_sales = Product.objects.filter(
    category__in=sub_core_categories
)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in this case query will be empty because all products are connected to core category. The problem is to find all products within top-level Categories connected with core categpry as a parent

Comment: I think the best equivalent for this particular situation are files in folders. Single File knows only its parent directory, but this parent directory could be a sub-folder of its parent. I want to query top level folder for all files in subdirectories.

Comment: files are with core as False or True?

Comment: Files = Products, they have a category with core = True

Comment: almost perfect :) "category__in" is great solution (i didn't think about it) but this only works if all sub-categories are core. In my example "AI" isn't core but has core children, so the second query doesn't return it. For now, core category could be at max 4 level, but I don't want limit myself to max levels.

Comment: right. for that you need to run these steps recursively for each sub main category in the top level category. If you want, I can give an example for it.

Comment: I'll be thankful, my brain stops working after couple of hours figuring this problem :)

Comment: added the recursive method.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, but I get TypeError in  recursive_sub_category
    top_level_category.category_set.filter(core=True, main=False)
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Comment: after that changes I've got error with 22 arguments, but I changed .append(*_sub_core_categories) to .extend(_sub_core_categories) and it seems to work !